# Suppose $G$ is a commutative group, and $H_1,H_2$ are subgroups, then $H_1H_2$ is a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a commutative group, and $H_1,H_2$ are subgroups, then I believe that $H_1H_2$ is a subgroup, but I'm not sure so I try to prove it:

$H_1H_2 := \{h_1h_2 : h_i \in H_i\}$. So if $h \in H_1H_2$ then $h = h_1h_2$ for $h_i \in H_i$.

I checked that it contains the identity, is closed under multiplication and each element has an inverse. I believe $H_1H_2$ being a group strongly depends upon the commutativity of $G$ is this correct?

Comment: That's correct. Write down the proof for closed under multiplication. There commutativity is used! (It's also used for the inverse elements)

Comment: No, it doesn't depend *strongly* on commutativity of $G$.  Any group $G$, subgroups $H_1,H_2$ with $H_2\leqslant N_G(H_1)$ would work.